# Bathroom Lighting in the UK: Is British Standard BS 7671 a required LAW

Tags: united-kingdom, regulations

I've looked high and low on Google to find out if its law within the UK that bathroom lights or fittings are required to use IP44 rating or above. The only bits of information looks like a regulation and unable to find it out if its actual law for a home owner or landlord to install electrical fitting within [ZONE 1 or 2](http://www.homebase.co.uk/cmsresource/image/128710/landscape_ratio7x3/700/300/7f276c9e52c6149360a6a7bb5936a35e/fb/bathroom-lighting-buying-guide---zones-image.jpg) set out by [BS 7671](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS_7671) (the IET Wiring Regulations)

Comment: Yes, legal regulations **are** laws. What exactly are you asking - that it's okay to ignore requirements based on what the requirements are called?

Comment: [This discussion](http://www.theiet.org/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=205&threadid=21878) suggests that BS7671 is not statutory; but as a recognised code of best practise, failure to conform to it would put you at risk of prosecution under statutory regulations. Having said that, BS7671 is mentioned in some secondary legislation, e.g. [The Electricity Safety, Quality and Continuity Regulations 2002](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2002/2665/contents/made).